# How to get a function pointer to a member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I was working on a project where I needed to get involved with function pointers, more specifically function pointer to member functions. I have read almost all the related questions, however none of them describing my specific problem. So, I will try to describe my problem by a simple example.

Let's assume that I have three different header files with different classes, like given below:

foo1.h

```
struct Foo1{
    int a1;
    double b1;
    
    void (Foo2::*fp)(const double);
}
```

foo2.h

```
#include "foo1.h"

class Foo2{
public:
    void print_foo2(const double p){
        cout << "From Foo2: " << p << endl;
    }
    
    Foo1 foo1;
}
```

foo3.h

```
class Foo3 : public Foo2{
    Foo1 foo1;
    
    foo1.fp = &Foo2::print_foo2; // cannot do that
}
```

So, one of the member variables of struct `Foo1` is a function pointer to the member function of `Foo2`, namely `print_foo2`. For that reason, I create instance of object `foo1` and assign it a pointer to the `print_foo2`. Class `Foo3` inherits from class `Foo2`.

I noted that, as I thought, may be it can be useful information for solution of the problem. However, I cannot get that pointer to the function as `Foo2` is not recognized inside struct `Foo1`. Even including `foo2.h` in `foo1.h` doesn't help. If I am not mistaken, this is because `Foo1` requires `Foo2` for its member variable during construction, but in the same way `Foo2` requires `Foo1` to be constructed. So, this creates a deadlock.

Is it the cause of the problem? If yes, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both `Foo2` and `Foo3` need the definition of `Foo1`, they should both `#include "foo1.h"`. Without the definition of `Foo1` the compiler will not be able to calculate the size of neither `Foo2` nor `Foo3`.

`Foo1` on the other hand does *not* need the definition of `Foo2` and can therefore forward declare `Foo2` to resolve the deadlock. The pointer (`fp`) it keeps will have the same size no matter how `Foo2` is defined which is why a forward declaration is enough.

Comments inline:

```cpp
// foo1.h
#pragma once

class Foo2;       // forward declaration

struct Foo1{
    int a1;
    double b1;
    
    void (Foo2::*fp)(const double);
};
```

```cpp
// foo3.h
#pragma once

#include "foo2.h"
#include "foo1.h" // not strictly needed since `foo2.h` includes it

class Foo3 : public Foo2{

    // proper initalization:

    Foo1 foo1{1, 3.141, &Foo2::print_foo2};
};
```

Note: In your code, both `Foo2` and `Foo3` has a `Foo1` member variable. That means that `Foo3` has 2 in total. If you only one *one* `Foo1` in `Foo3` and instead want `Foo3` to initialize the `Foo1` in the inherited `Foo2`, you can remove the `Foo1` member from `Foo3` and initialize the base class (`Foo2`) like so:

```cpp
class Foo3 : public Foo2{
public:
    Foo3() : Foo2{1, 3.141, &Foo2::print_foo2} {}
};
```